# UNICODE_STRING to std String Conversion

Tags: windows, driver, kernel-mode, filter-driver

I am using **pFileObject->FileName** to get the name of file opened in a kernel mode filter driver.This file name returned by this is in the form of **[UNICODE_STRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**. I want to convert it into **std String**. What is the method ??? Please do provide example if possible...
Below is the code

```
NTSTATUS FsFilterDispatchCreate(
    __in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    __in PIRP           Irp
    )
{
    PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;

    DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &pFileObject->FileName);

    return FsFilterDispatchPassThrough(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

Comment: Two things you should never do in a device driver: assuming that the default *new* operator works and assuming that there's a valid code page.  Do **not** use std::string in a driver.

Comment: As Hans noted, this plan is a non-starter. There is no MSVCR90.DLL in kernel mode.

Comment: @Hans I am not planning to use std::string in KM rather i will use it in UM

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Hans' comment. Making std:: classes work in Windows kernel mode is extremely difficult if not impossible. The default WinDDK environment is C rather than C++. Your best bet is to convert UNICODE_STRING to ANSI null-terminated string. (You can print it with DbgPrint("%s"...) etc). See example below.

```
UNICODE_STRING tmp;

// ...

ANSI_STRING dest;
ULONG unicodeBufferSize = tmp.Length;
// Length of unicode string in bytes must be enough to keep ANSI string
dest.Buffer = (PCHAR)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, unicodeBufferSize+1);
// check for allocation failure... 
dest.Length = 0;
dest.MaximumLength = unicodeBufferSize+1;

RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString(&dest, &tmp, FALSE);
// check for failure...
dest.Buffer[dest.Length] = 0; // now we get it in dest.Buffer
```